# IGRAPH conversion from R code to Python variant

Tags: python, r, igraph

I am unable to find an equivalent conversion of graph_from_data_frame present in R into something in Python

What I have done is :

```
graph_from_data_frame(d = dataframe_1[,c("ID_TO","ID_FROM")], directed = TRUE, vertices = sort(unique(unlist(dataframe_1))))
```

Output of the above :

```
IGRAPH DN-- 195 201 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
 [1] 46753->46627 46737->46642 46753->46629 46737->46629 46646->46600  enter code here... (and so on)...
```

What i tried in python is the following :

```
# Convert dataframe to matrix
edges = dataframe_1.as_matrix(columns=None)
# create directed graph
MAP = Graph.TupleList(directed=True, edges = edges)
```

This gave me below output, which is incorrect (i am getting the output reversed) probably because I was not able to do a sort(unique(unlist())) variant in python. But i am unsure.
Output from python code :

```
IGRAPH DN-- 339 201 --
+ attr: name (v)
+ edges (vertex names):
46627->46753, 46642->46737, 46629->46753, 46629->46737, 46600->46646
```

I came to know that there is no direct variant of **graph_from_data_frame** in R into anything in Python, but any lead to this approach and this result is appreciated.

Sample data from dataframe :

```
 ID_FROM       ID_TO
0    46627          46753
1    46642          46737
2    46629          46753
3    46629          46737
4    46600          46646
5    46552          46633
```

I have gone through many results from google differentiating about IGRAPH in R vs Python but nothing helped to the sue-case that I am working on.

Comment: can you `dput` your `data frame` sample?

Comment: @SandipanDey - I have updated the above with data as well.
The order of vertices is what I think is going wrong somehow.

Comment: @SandipanDey - also the `dput` of data is as follows :


`> dput(dataframe_1)
structure(list(ID_FROM = c("46627", "46642", 
"46629", "46629", "46600", "46552"), ID_TO = c("46753", 
"46737", "46753", "46737", "46646", "46633"), .Names = c("ID_FROM", 
"ID_TO"), row.names = c(NA, -201L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: posted `R` and `python` code for `igraph`

Answer (score 2):

## R Code

```
library(igraph)
dataframe_1 <- read.table(text='     ID_FROM        ID_TO
                                0    46627          46753
                                1    46642          46737
                                2    46629          46753
                                3    46629          46737
                                4    46600          46646
                                5    46552          46633', header=TRUE)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = dataframe_1[,c("ID_TO","ID_FROM")], directed = TRUE, vertices = sort(unique(unlist(dataframe_1))))
plot(g)
```

[image]

## Python Code

```
from igraph import *
import pandas as pd

dataframe_1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_FROM':[46627, 46642, 46629, 46629, 46600, 46552], 'ID_TO':[46753,46737,46753,46737,46646,46633]})
#print dataframe_1
g = Graph(directed=True)
for index, row in dataframe_1.iterrows():
   g.add_vertex(str(row['ID_FROM']))
   g.add_vertex(str(row['ID_TO']))
   g.add_edge(str(row['ID_FROM']), str(row['ID_TO'])) 
g.vs["label"] = g.vs["name"]
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: When run for the actual data , this gave me a big ball of graph without edges. 
Any idea why?

attaching a sample screenshot below

Comment: did you add vertices and then edges one by one? you may try some layouts while plotting and change the vertex size.